# What does "enable regular expressions in formatter markers" do?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

Recently I came across this option "enable regular expressions in formatter markers" in the IntelliJ Code Style settings. I couldn't find any information online on what it does. Google just turns up a few diffs and chinese links.

Does anyone know?

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ settings dialog]

Comment: Have you checked https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/settings-code-style.html#formatter-control ?

Comment: There it is! I wonder why google didn't turn that up? Anyway, even if I had found that page, I'd still had to ask, because the explanation in the docs could really use an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [Formatter Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/settings-code-style.html#formatter-control) documentation.

It changes how the two fields `Formatter off` and `Formatter on` are interpreted. Normally they're just fixed strings that it searches for in comments.

If you check the regular expression box, they're regular expressions that are matched in comments. So if you enter

```
Formatter off: @f.*off
```

you can use a comment like

```
//@f--k off
```

to turn formatting off.